# Is Shinji omnipotent during third impact

Tags: evangelion

I know that during the third impact in EOE, basically an anti AT-field is deployed. Everyone thus no longer has a barrier and become LCL. It is speculated that Shinji is near-God-like since he is the center of third impact. He can choose to stop the process (people can return to their form from LCL). However he didn't do much else other than return back to human form, leading me to question that if he actually is omnipotent during the third impact, or he can only decide on the impact process.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't believe that it was ever mentioned that the controller of Third Impact would be omnipotent, only that they would control how it would proceed. The Angels, Seele, and Gendou all plotted for control to initiate different forms of Instrumentality. But in the end Rei/Lillith gives control to Shinji who chooses individuality. So Rei/Lillith terminates the anti AT-field and Shinji and Asuka reform (and the rest of humanity in time I assume).

Comment: However it seems Gendou want to use it to "rebel" god and meet with Yui, which kind of suggest that he can do more than the the flow of process, no?

Comment: Well the way he wanted to *meet* Yui was for humanity to become one being, i.e. Instrumentality, so I wouldn't say it included making him omnipotent.